# TensorFlow on Apple M1 without Metal - is it possible?

Tags: python, tensorflow, apple-m1

I have a 2017 Intel iMac on which I develop TensorFlow apps. I am on the latest version of everything (as at April 2023) - Python 3.11.3, Tensorflow 2.12.0, numpy 1.24.2.

I have bought a cheap secondhand Mac Mini (2020 M1) to offload some of the training. The experiments I have done with Metal give me worse performance training on the GPU than on my iMac. This seems to be a general problem with certain network configurations. Also, to go back to an earlier version of TF means I have to forego some newer features that I am using in 2.12.

However, good news, the M1 Mac Mini is about twice the speed of the iMac for Python programs that don't use TF.

Can I install my latest-version-of-everything environment on the M1 Mini and just not use the GPU? When I pip install tensorflow, I get the message:

`ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow-macos (from versions: none) ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow-macos`

Python 3.11 seems a lot faster than 3.10, so it would be good to keep that. How can I find out what versions of everything tensorflow-macos needs? Is there a version of tensorflow-macos that is compatible with Python 3.11?

Just to reiterate, I do not want to use the GPU for training, just have the most up to date versions running on the CPU.

Thanks,

Julian

Comment: probably `with tf.device("/CPU:0"): ...` is enough?

Comment: That will enable the training to work without the GPU, but it doesn't help me get TensorFlow installed in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked around the problem using Docker. By specifying the latest Python image, and installing TensorFlow in the Dockerfile, I can use the latest versions of everything. The training is perhaps 20% faster now on the M1 Mac Mini than on my iMac. The main determinant seems to be the larger number of cores on the 2017 iMac than on the 2020 Mac Mini.

I am assuming that going to an M2 Mac Mini with 8 cores will be a bigger improvement still.